# Vue.js webpack sass-loader issue with my .scss file

Tags: vue.js, sass-loader, webpack-3

I am using style-loader, node-sass, sass-loader packages as stated in the doc.. 
I added to my ***webpack.base.conf.js*** the following modules rules

```
  {
    test: /\.(s?)css$/,
    use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
  },
```

In my **main.js** , I import my .scss files

```
 import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css' // Theme UI
import './assets/scss/index.scss' // Customize UI
```

but I get an error during build phase as the theme css are loaded but then

```
error  in ./src/assets/scss/index.scss
 Module build failed:
 @import './globals/index.scss';
 ^
```

It's not clear for me how to handle correctly both css and scss files...  too many 'solutions' when googling on it ... cannoit find the latest one

feedback welcome

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED.. ( using webpack 3.6.0

**webpack.base.config.js**

**NO** need for

{
    test: /.(s?)css$/,
    use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']
  },

so I removed it

In **utils.js** , I shoudl have my css-loader

```
exports.cssLoaders = function (options) {
  options = options || {}

  const cssLoader = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  }
```

main.js   removed the import ..

```
// import './element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css' // Theme UI
// import './assets/scss/index.scss' // Customize UI
```

**App.vue** , inserted the @import ...

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css";
@import "./assets/scss/index.scss";
#app {
```

Should take care about the nested @import.. in the assets/scss/.. structure

```
src
  assets
    scss
      globals
        index.scss
          // .border-black { border: 1px solid #000; }...
      mixins
        animations
            index.scss
              // ...
        breakpoints
            index.scss
              // ...
        buttons
            index.scss
              // ...
        tables
            index.scss
              // ... 
        transitions
            index.scss
              // ...
        index.scss
          // @import 'breakpoints/index.scss'; @import 'animations/index.scss'; @import 'buttons/index.scss'; @import 'tables/index.scss'; @import 'transitions/index.scss'; ...
      vars
        colors
            index.scss
                // $bg-white: #fff; $bg-white-light: #f5f5f5; $bg-black: #000; ...
        index.scss
            // @import 'colors/index.scss';
      index.scss
        // @import 'globals/index.scss'; @import 'mixins/index.scss'; @import 'vars/index.scss';
```